# ZSH + OH-MY-ZSH odd text on start up (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Running zsh + oh-my-zsh on my cygwin install. Whenever I start a new ZSH session (new mintty, tmux, etc..) it ouputs the text below. I don't think it's affecting the performance of ZSH but it is SUPER annoying.

```
add-zsh-hook () {
        emulate -L zsh
        local -a hooktypes
        hooktypes=(chpwd precmd preexec periodic zshaddhistory zshexit zsh_direc                                                                                                                                                                                                  tory_name)
        local usage="Usage: $0 hook function\nValid hooks are:\n  $hooktypes"
        local opt
        local -a autoopts
        integer del list help
        while getopts "dDhLUzk" opt
        do
                case $opt in
                        (d) del=1  ;;
                        (D) del=2  ;;
                        (h) help=1  ;;
                        (L) list=1  ;;
                        ([Uzk]) autoopts+=(-$opt)  ;;
                        (*) return 1 ;;
                esac
        done
        shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
        if (( list ))
        then
                typeset -mp "(${1:-${(@j:|:)hooktypes}})_functions"
                return $?
        elif (( help || $# != 2 || ${hooktypes[(I)$1]} == 0 ))
        then
                print -u$(( 2 - help )) $usage
                return $(( 1 - help ))
        fi
        local hook="${1}_functions"
        local fn="$2"
        if (( del ))
        then
                if (( ${(P)+hook} ))
                then
                        if (( del == 2 ))
                        then
                                set -A $hook ${(P)hook:#${~fn}}
                        else
                                set -A $hook ${(P)hook:#$fn}
                        fi
                        if (( ! ${(P)#hook} ))
                        then
                                unset $hook
                        fi
                fi
        else
                if (( ${(P)+hook} ))
                then
                        if (( ${${(P)hook}[(I)$fn]} == 0 ))
                        then
                                set -A $hook ${(P)hook} $fn
                        fi
                else
                        set -A $hook $fn
                fi
                autoload $autoopts -- $fn
        fi
}
compdump () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -XUz
}
compinit () {
        emulate -L zsh
        setopt extendedglob
        typeset _i_dumpfile _i_files _i_line _i_done _i_dir _i_autodump=1
        typeset _i_tag _i_file _i_addfiles _i_fail=ask _i_check=yes _i_name
        while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 = -[dDiuC] ]]
        do
                case "$1" in
                        (-d) _i_autodump=1
                                shift
                                if [[ $# -gt 0 && "$1" != -[dfQC] ]]
                                then
                                        _i_dumpfile="$1"
                                        shift
                                fi ;;
                        (-D) _i_autodump=0
                                shift ;;
                        (-i) _i_fail=ign
                                shift ;;
                        (-u) _i_fail=use
                                shift ;;
                        (-C) _i_check=
                                shift ;;
                esac
        done
        typeset -gA _comps _services _patcomps _postpatcomps
        typeset -gA _compautos
        typeset -gA _lastcomp
        if [[ -n $_i_dumpfile ]]
        then
                typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="$_i_dumpfile"
        else
                typeset -g _comp_dumpfile="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump"
        fi
        typeset -ga _comp_options
        _comp_options=(bareglobqual extendedglob glob multibyte nullglob rcexpan                                                                                                                                                                                                  dparam unset NO_allexport NO_aliases NO_cshnullglob NO_cshjunkiequotes NO_errexi                                                                                                                                                                                                  t NO_globsubst NO_histsubstpattern NO_ignorebraces NO_ignoreclosebraces NO_kshgl                                                                                                                                                                                                  ob NO_ksharrays NO_kshtypeset NO_markdirs NO_octalzeroes NO_shwordsplit NO_shglo                                                                                                                                                                                                  b NO_warncreateglobal)
        typeset -g _comp_setup='local -A _comp_caller_options;
             _comp_caller_options=(${(kv)options[@]});
             setopt localoptions localtraps ${_comp_options[@]};
             local IFS=$'\'\ \\t\\r\\n\\0\''
             exec </dev/null;
             trap - ZERR
             local -a reply
             local REPLY'
        typeset -ga compprefuncs comppostfuncs
        compprefuncs=()
        comppostfuncs=()
        : $funcstack
        compdef () {
                local opt autol type func delete eval new i ret=0 cmd svc
                local -a match mbegin mend
                emulate -L zsh
                setopt extendedglob
                if (( ! $# ))
                then
                        print -u2 "$0: I need arguments"
                        return 1
                fi
                while getopts "anpPkKde" opt
                do
                        case "$opt" in
                                (a) autol=yes  ;;
                                (n) new=yes  ;;
                                ([pPkK]) if [[ -n "$type" ]]
```

[limited by body text]

Comment: It outputs the entire script?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what script it is, but it does. My code got truncated due to character limits in questions. @AlG

Comment: Feels like there's a bad mode, etc. So instead of running the script, it's just cat-ing it.

Comment: I'm not sure. What would toy recommend I do? @AlG

Comment: I'd go looking for the script that includes this function and trace it to find out what user of it is causing it to be output. Then check permissions etc. It's more of a "you have to debug it" and less of a "I know what to do". Sorry!

Comment: This looks like the output of `functions` or `typeset -f` without further parameters. `add-zsh-hook`, `compdump` and `compinit` are part of zsh and are usually loaded with `autoload -Uz NAME` in `.zshrc` (maybe somewhere else with oh-my-zsh). The body of the `compdump` function indicates that it has not been used yet. I'd suggest looking for a standalone `functions` or `typeset -f` in your `.zshrc` and Oh-my-ZSH configuration and installation.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. And you can look at 

`cat ~/.zcompdump*`

I got the following output:

```
_comps=(
)

_services=(
)

_patcomps=(
)

_postpatcomps=(
)

_compautos=(
)


autoload -Uz

typeset -gUa _comp_assocs
_comp_assocs=( '' )
```

It means the failure is in autoload -Uz. If you type-in `autoload -Uz` in the zsh, you will get the exact output. If that's the issue, you can fix it by correcting the directory permissions.

```
compaudit | xargs chown -R :Users
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w
rm ~/.zcompdump*
```

To verify, make sure compaudit is outputting nothing. This worked for me and fixed the auto complete.

Link to related issue: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/630